# Special characters in pdo

Tags: php, pdo, special-characters

When I try to update my values it gives me the following error: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined.
This only occurs with special characters, for instance: (hello;) and not with (hello)
For some reason it can't find values with special characters and I can only insert them
and not update or remove it from my database.

And the database is already set on utf8.

```
public function update($data, $key, $value) {
    try { 

        $this->query = 'UPDATE ' . $this->table . ' SET ';

        array_walk($data, function($index, $key) {
            $this->query .= $key . ' = ' . ':' . $key . ', ';
        });

        $this->query = rtrim($this->query, " ,");

        $this->query .= " WHERE $key = :$value"; 

        $stmt = $this->db->prepare($this->query);

        $stmt->execute(array_merge($data, array($value => $value)));

        return true;

    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

An example how I use it:

```
if(isset($oldValue, $newValue)) {
$data['database']->update(array("name" => $newValue), "name", $oldValue);
}
```

The array is to give a key and a new value to update and after the comma is to search for the value in the table 'name'.

If someone knows a solution for this then I would be very happy, thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you give an example of how you’re calling `update`?

Comment: You need to remove the `$` sign from both `:$value` - Plus, it's hard to say but if you happen to be using the word `key`, - `key` is MySQL reserved word; *just an insight.*

Comment: @icktoofay see post above I edited it

Comment: @Fred-ii- no that is just how stackoverflow is displaying it, when using "" you can put a variable inside it

Comment: @user3139504 Ah, ok. Usually, binds do not have a `$` in them, least I never use them.

Comment: In your example code, are `$oldValue` and `$newValue` constants, or are they supplied by the user?

Comment: @icktoofay let me update it maybe then it will become more clearer

Comment: @icktoofay they are supplied by the user

Comment: @icktoofay I have edited my code can you check it for me. It still only works with values without ;-=` etc. –

Comment: @user3139504: You’re still using `$value` as the name of the parameter, which you shouldn’t be doing. Instead, hardcode it as `oldValue` or something. The `WHERE` clause should resemble `WHERE name = :name` or `WHERE name = :oldValue` or something, not `WHERE name = :Horace`.

Comment: @icktoofay I have double checked it and that is not the problem. This method works with all values except with those that have special characters inside it thats why this is so strange.

Answer (score 0):

You’re parameterizing *partly*, and that’s good, but you should probably be parameterizing *fully*. To demonstrate more lucidly, let us assume we are calling `update(array("occupation" => "poet"), "name", "Horace")` with `$this->table` set to `"persons"`. We’d then be composing this SQL:

```sql
UPDATE persons SET occupation = :occupation WHERE name = : Horace
```

We’d then execute it with these parameter values:

```
occupation => poet
:Horace => Horace
```

The `occupation = :occupation` part is excellent and correct; but `name = : Horace` and `:Horace => Horace` is wrong. You instead should probably be composing a query like this:

```sql
UPDATE persons SET occupation = :occupation WHERE name = :name
```

And these parameter values:

```
occupation => poet
name => Horace
```

If you ever have a case where you call it like `update(array("occupation" => "unemployed"), "occupation", "poet")`, however, you might have some issues, as you’d need to have two different parameters for `occupation` (one old, one new), and you’d be calling both `occupation`. One would win out over the other and your `UPDATE` would do nothing. So you’ll have to deal with that case, but otherwise, it should be fairly straightforward.